# Overture/Stackoverflow/VDM projects corrupted/vanished

Tags: eclipse, vdm++

I've spent the past 2 weeks working on a coursework for College, I had pretty completed 90% of it. I decided to open Overture now and seems like all my projects have corrupted :((((((

http://gyazo.com/8e25549bbca700a22399e736a88a1996

If anyone has any suggestions/ideas about how I could recover from this I'd greatly appreciate it. I've tried 'Compare with -> Local history' but did not work. Little upset right now :[

Answer (score 0):

The VDM source files in an Overture project are simple text. If those files are not corrupt (open them outside Overture with a text editor), then create a new workspace, create new project(s) and copy the files into them.

If the source files are corrupt, the only hope is if you have some sort of backup, I'm afraid.

We've never seen Overture corrupt sources before. The only component that could do this is the editor, and it deals with one file at a time. Do you have any idea why or when this happened? What version and platform are you running?